# Proper abbreviation for "vorherigen"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, abbreviation

I came across a German sentence that made me pause.

> Fehler bei vorherig. Install.

It is intended to be the translation for an error message that says: "Error on prior install"

Is "vorherig." a proper abbreviation for "vorherigen" in this situation?

Personally, I would have written, "Fehler bei vorherigen Installation," but then I realized that it might be a way of abbreviating the sentence.

Comment: *vorh.* will do. Or use *voriger*.

Comment: As a side note, the full sentence would need to be either "Fehler bei der _vorherigen_ Installation" or "Fehler bei _vorheriger_ Installation". The first is the "completely correct" version, the second is already some kind of shorted. You'll find the latter for example in a headline, or in short messages like in your scenario.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a "proper" abbreviation in the sense of "commonly used". I don't think there is one for *vorheriger*. Same is true for *Install.* as an abbreviation for *Installation*.

I see how these came to be. The German translation is obviously much longer than the English text, there probably wasn't enough space on the UI, so they made up abbreviations that were as unambiguous as possible while just fitting the space. I have done similar things.

As Janka states in a comment, *voriger* would have been a good/better alternative (if the *previous* installation is what is meant). The abbreviation *vorh.* is ambiguous, I would normally understand it to mean *vorhanden*.